# sed unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, sed, sh

I have this bash code

```
REPLACEMENT="s:define('CP_DIRECTORY.*:define('CP_DIRECTORY), ('"${NEWLOCATION}"');:;"
sed -i $REPLACEMENT $INITDATA;
```

It returns

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
```

I am trying to replace a line in initdata.php that looks like this:

```
define( 'CP_DIRECTORY', 'admin' );
```

to this

```
define( 'CP_DIRECTORY', 'AJgBCecvPBUnPZCLvKukyzfehWrsF5wI' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Put single quotes around the entire `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's:AdminCP = .*:AdminCP = "/home/pi/forums/AJgBCecvPBUnPZCLvKukyzfehWrsF5wI";:' forums/initdata.php
```

Otherwise, the command is split on the spaces. Also, you need a dot before the asterisk, otherwise you're just saying "zero or more spaces".

Comment: @DavidDiaz: Your question had none of that in it. Why didn't you post what you're actually trying to do. Please edit your question so it reflects your actual conditions.

Comment: Updated, sorry. I saw this earlier and I tried to edit it but my internet kept on cutting out due to extreme packet loss so I just commented.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work thanks to Dennis Williamson saying that I needed to quote the sed command & http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/sed-with-bash-variables-304260/

Final code was

```
    REPLACEMENT="define( 'CP_DIRECTORY' ), ( '"
    REPLACEMENT=$REPLACEMENT$NEWLOCATION;
    REPLACEMENT=$REPLACEMENT"' );:;";
    sed -i "s:define( 'CP_DIRECTORY.*:$REPLACEMENT" $INITDATA;
```